# SQLite table processing in python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a table

| id | friends |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | [1, 4] |
| 4 | [1, 2] |

my task is to build all the connections of the users' friends

If friends is NULL, then we go through all other IDs.
And look for who has this ID as a friend.

ID with 1 is NULL.
We use the script to look for who has 1 in their friends.
It's IDs numbered 3 and 4.
So, memorize 3 and 4, after you go through all - save this array to the first one.
And so on with each line.

So, I have to determine which IDs are friends with the ID I'm looking for.
After determining, I will have an array, the same array I write instead of NULL.

So I should get:

| id | friends |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [3, 4] |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | [1, 4] |
| 4 | [1, 2] |

But if it's not NULL, you still need to go through all users and record if there are any changes

ID 4 has a list like this [1, 2].
But ID 3 has user 4 ([1, 4]).
So I add 4 to the existing list.

That's what it was:
[1, 2]

Here's what it should be:
[1, 2, 3]

(Important, you have to do .sort())

what I did.

```
for row in cursor:
    id = row[0]
    friends = row[1]
    print(id, friends)
    if friends == None:
        new_friends = []
        for row in cursor:
            fr_id = row[0]
            str_fr_friends = row[1]
            if str_fr_friends != None:
                fr_id = row[0]
                str_fr_friends = row[1]
                fr_friends = json.loads(str_fr_friends)
                # print(fr_id, fr_friends)
                if fr_id not in new_friends:
                    if id in fr_friends:
                        new_friends.append(fr_id)
                        print(id, new_friends)
                        # print(fr_id, fr_friends) 
        new_friends = json.dumps(new_friends)
        if new_friends != []:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE Users SET friends = ? WHERE id = ?", (new_friends, id))
```

I decided to start processing from cases where friends is NULL.

My problem is that the code only edits the 1st line. If I run it again it goes to the second line.

I added a part to handle cases where friends is not NULL but it made things worse.

QUESTION: How can I make the script edit every line?

my database is 850,000,000 lines, so I'm reading it line by line. Maybe I should use a different way of reading it, but it is definitely not possible to load it completely into a file

Comment: Shawn, I don't understand you, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Shawn, Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the large number of records and table-wide aggregation operation, it might be most efficient to use a query, as opposed to loading most/all of your records into memory via Python. The query scans each row, and performs two operations:

1. if `friends` is `null`, then it finds all other `id`s in the table that have the `null` friend `id` in its `friends` array and aggregates the results
2. otherwise, the `friends` array is merged, via a `union all`, with all other `id`s that contain the original `id` in its `friends` array

---

```
select p.id, case when p.friends is null then (select json_group_array(p1.id) 
       from people p1 where exists (select 1 from json_each(p1.friends) v where v.value = p.id)) 
    else (select json_group_array(v1.pid) from (select p1.id pid from people p1 
          where exists (select 1 from json_each(p1.friends) v where v.value = p.id)
          union all
          select v.value pid from json_each(p.friends) v) v1) end
from people p
```

Comment: Oh I am confident that *might* can be replaced by *certainly*  in your first sentence.  Python users often neglect sql processing and this is a textbook example at any volume, esp. the OP’s.

Comment: Ajax1234, I don't really understand it. Could you describe your solution in simpler words?